# Abstract Algebra Finding All Orbits - Is my answers correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups, group-actions

Hope you are well.

I'm posting the following as a favour on behalf of a friend who is not a native speaker, she just wants to confirm her answer is indeed correct, or if it could be answered in a more efficient manner.

I have uploaded an image of her question and her answer respectivly, sorry iam unable to write it out due to my lack of mathmatic symbolic knowledge.

[image: Image of Question]

[image: Image of Answer]

Any input would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer is correct.  It's probably better to use the orbit stabilizer theorem to conclude that there is a single orbit (i.e., that the action is transitive).

Answer (score 1):

Her calculations are perfectly correct. To be honest, it could happen that there is precisely one orbit, in which case the action is called *transitive*.

Besides, if she has learned the orbit-stabilizer theorem, she can check that $$|{\rm orb}(1)|=\frac{|G|}{|{\rm Stab}(1)|}=\frac{6}{2}=3,$$ but the size of the underlying set $H$ is precisely $3$. That is, the orbit containing $1$ must be the whole set! This also indicates the uniqueness of orbits in this action.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my friend would like to understand the formula by definition as she is struggling to work it out.  Can you offer any help on this? Regards

Comment: Here is a link for orbit-stabilizer theorem: https://mathtuition88.com/2016/07/21/orbit-stabilizer-theorem-with-proof/.